# What's the difference between a reorder buffer and an instruction window?

Tags: computer-architecture

In an out-of-order processor, what is the difference between a reorder buffer and an instruction window?

Wikipedia says:
"In particular, in a conventional design, the instruction window consists of all instructions which are in the Reorder Buffer (ROB)."

Does this mean that the instruction window isn't a seperate hardware structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct.  The *instruction window* is not a hardware structure.  It is the set of instructions that is contained in the reorder buffer at any moment in time.  Looked at another way: the reorder buffer is a *container* (like a drinking cup is a container) and the instruction window is the thing the reorder buffer *contains* (like milk, juice or water is the thing contained in a drinking cup.)